# Jaspersoft/ Jasperreports: How to pass parameter list to IN clause?

Tags: jasper-reports

I cannot make it work with ${P} and passing and string with "'parameter1',"parameter2'" form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this can be achieved with:

```
SELECT COLUMN1
FROM TABLE
WHERE $X{IN, COLUMN1, parameterList}
```

Then parameter list has to be a Java Collection and defined as follows:

[Jaspersoft list parameter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOwaR.png)

Reference: https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters-queries